# How to make that semi circle in navigation bar like flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

I need help please on how to do the navigation bottom bar as shown in the image below in flutter, that semi circle in the center!

[check the image here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjILI.png)

Comment: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/bottom-bar-navigation-with-fab/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [persistent_bottom_nav_ba](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package.

If you set `navBarStyle` property to `NavBarStyle.style17`, you’ll have semi circle in the center!